# Send an individual attachment from Outlook to OneNote

Tags: outlook, onenote

I frequently use the "Send to OneNote" button in MS Outlook to save emails and their attachments in my notebooks. This allows me to accumulate an array of different inputs (e.g. email, reports, estimates in spreadsheets, etc, etc - I'm preaching to the converted, I think).

Often, I'd like to move a single email attachment to a OneNote page. My process for this is:

- open the email
- save the attachment to the Desktop
- open the desired destination page in OneNote
- drag the file from the Desktop to the OneNote page
- select the "Insert the file as printout so I can add notes to it" option

I do this to save only the attachment I need and avoid saving the contents of the email and all the other attachments.

Can I send an individual attachment directly from Outlook to a OneNote page?

Comment: I was able to answer my own question before even finishing asking the question. Thought I should still post it in case it's helpful to others. Am I misbehaving by doing this?

Comment: No, it is the best thing to do as others are able to Google it

Comment: This is more appropriate for SuperUser, isn't it?

Comment: It's even encouraged to answer your own questions, as long as the question and answer are both high-quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly after writing this question (actually, *as* I was writing the question!), I found an answer that works for me.

Click and drag the attachment filename from the Outlook email directly to a OneNote page. The file insert dialog then pops up allowing insertion of an icon or printout.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for attachments which display "inline" with the message, with their icon. Dragging and dropping to OneNote simply pastes the icon, and not inserts the document as expected. I am using Office 2013.

Comment: @StockB, it gave me that option during insertion, try it again maybe it has been fixed.

Comment: great, I was looking for this solution. Works fine